# `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when starting Python script in VS Code on macOS

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a Python script from Visual Studio code, but the script fails to run and crashes with a `SyntaxError` pointing to the comment at the beginning of `launch.json`.

`launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python | Default",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Terminal Output:

```
File ".../.vscode/launch.json", line 2
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

`settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python"
}
```

---

I was working on my Windows machine earlier and all of this worked perfectly fine. For some reason, VSCode is trying to run the `launch.json` file through Python and `//` is an invalid comment syntax in Python. If I remove the comments, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../.vscode/launch.json", line 8, in <module>
    "stopOnEntry": false,
NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

If I use Python's `False`, I don't crash but nothing happens and my script does not run. It seems very much like `launch.json` is being parsed by Python erroneously. Any fix for this?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found my problem. I did not update the `program` key to always point to my `main.py`. Instead, the current open file was being executed as a Python script -- `launch.json` Changing the `program` key or navigating to a different file solved the problem. Obvious once you notice it!

For Example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Solution 1

I consider that an easier solution is:

1. Close the launch.json on the editor group
2. Open the python file such as main.py to be debugged
3. [Run]-[Start Debugging] (F5)

As Nick mentioned, when focusing on the launch.json in the editor, the debug system runs on the launch.json itself, not a python file.

### Solution 2

Modify the "program" in the launch.json as below:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
```

It corresponds to

> the program key to always point to main.py

as Nick said.

Note that the above modification may not work well if the main.py places in a deep directory.

Comment: That kinda makes sense, although in my case I didn't even have launch.json open. I opened it, switched to my .py module, then launched the debugger. It worked after that. I don't get it, but I won't "look a gift horse in the mouth".

Answer (score 4):

Closing `launch.json` if it is open for editing may solve the issue

If `launch.json` is the latest open file, VSCode may be trying to run `launch.json` as a Python module (despite the fact that it's clearly not a Python module).

See the `NameError` in the OP's third screenshot - looks like Python interpreter running against `launch.json`

(Note: the contribution of this answer is solely to put the crux of Haru's Solution 1.1 and Nick's own self-diagnosis into simple language in the answer's first line)